# how to call subactivity of another application android?

Tags: android

To call main activity I saw componentName class in android.

```
intent = new Intent(new ComponentName(packageNam,classname);
```

if same is used in case of child activity, I got error ,
`"is activity delcared in andorid manifest?"` like error.

how to call app1 child activity in app2 by using intent ?
In app1 the activity is declared like this in manifest

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MessageCompose" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="false">
- <intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" /> 
  <data android:scheme="mailto" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
  </intent-filter>
- <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" /> 
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
- <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name">
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" /> 
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on how [intents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) work in Android. Since the component you're launching is in another app, you can't access the component directly. In short, you need some way to identify the app1 child activity with an intent filter, then call that from app2 using something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: how can i know the child activity URI

Answer (score 0):

Please declare that activity in app1/AndroidManifest.xml